# How to show $z$ choose $n$ is bounded sequence, where $z$ is complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a complex number $z$ and a positive integer $n$, we define "$z$ choose $n$" by $$\frac{z(z-1)\cdots(z-n+1)}{n!}.$$

How can we show that the sequence of all $z$ choose $n$ ($n\ge 1$) is a bounded sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the sequence where $z$ is fixed and $n=1,2,3,\ldots$? It's not bounded! For example, when $z=-2$, $z(z-1)\cdots(z-n+1)/n! = (-1)^n (n+1)!/n! = (-1)^n (n+1)$.